# access two devices on different subnets

Tags: ethernet, ipv4, ip-camera

I have a PC (Ubuntu 16.04) with two ethernet ports, and to each of them I connected one camera.
These are the camera addresses (I can change if necessary):

```
Camera 1: 169.254.146.101
Camera 2: 169.254.146.102
```

**What I want is to be able to connect the cameras to ANY of the ethernet ports of my PC and access the cameras simultaneously**

I tried three different setting on the computer side, but all of them allowed me to connect to just one cammera at the time:

Config 1:

```
Ethernet 1: 169.254.146.100
Ethernet 2: 169.254.146.100
```

Config 2:

```
Ethernet 1: 169.254.146.99
Ethernet 2: 169.254.146.100
```

Config 3:

```
Ethernet 1: 169.254.146.100
Ethernet 2: 169.254.147.100
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont 100% know if it matters, but had you tried to connect both cameras to a little switch and then this switch to your computer? Just for test if this will work

Comment: I tried and it works, but this whole system is meant to be mobile and fit in a package as small as possible. Besides it runs in 12V and I would have to deal with a supply for the switch.